# php: how to create a new form

Tags: php

This is a newbie question...

I receive data from the user via a form, if one of the fields I get is marked 'yes' I want to send him a new form.

How is this done?

edit: I know how to check the value of my original form's variable via $_POST. I know the conditionals, I'm asking for the syntax for *creating* the new form or redirecting the user to another html page with the new form.

Comment: You only need to wrap the '<form>...</form>' within an if statement checking for the value 'yes' in the proper $_POST variable. The form won't be printed if the conditional statement is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply break out of the PHP block to output regular HTML:

```
<?php
    /* Processing */
    if($checked) {
?>
<form>
  <!-- etc. -->
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Some people prefer the `if() : /* ... */ endif;` construct here, but that's merely a syntax difference.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would use an if statement to check the variable, if it is what you expect you display the form. Without example code of what you have tried, it is kind of hard to answer this accurately.

Comment: yes, I know how to check the variable. What's the syntax for creating a new form and send it to the user?